# How to send a message to the Master Class of a class?

Tags: cocoa

Quick Question:

I am creating an object from the `MainWindowController`:

```
about = [[About alloc]init];
```

In the Class About I do my Init:

```
-(id)init{

    if(!_viewAbout){
        [NSBundle loadNibNamed:@"About" owner:self];
        [NSApp beginSheet:self.viewAbout modalForWindow:*?????* modalDelegate:self didEndSelector:NULL  contextInfo:NULL];
    }
    return self;
}
```

My problem is that the Window is created in the `MainWindowController`.  My question is how to call/send a message to the creator of the class if the class itself doesn't know the master class?

Comment: NSWindowControllers have a property of their NSWindow (self.window)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, most classes have self.superclass and just super, like

```
[super someMethod....
```

or

```
[self.superclass blegh....
```

Or are you asking for the class that creates another class ? If that is the case, you need to declare the creator class inside the other one, some (id) variable would do the trick.

But the most popular design pattern on the mac is the delegate pattern, and once you start using that you will love it. Declaring a delegate is usually the way Cocoa and UIKit do things, but other programming languages might not. Obj-C doesn't have any magic variables like python f.ex. has. Either you have a delegate or you have a declared variable which you would set right after the init/alloc stuff.

Also your (init) call doesn't look right. Usually it looks like :

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Here you could declare your setting.
    }
    return self;
}
```

But my opinion is that if you are declaring a singular pattern, you would call a specific method in your class, like you do with so many classes on the iOS/Cocoa, like :

```
[someclass DefaultClass]
```

This would be your init class where you would do init, unless the class had been declared before and then you would just return the object.